# Swipe Action Recording Roboscript for firebase Test lab in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, firebase-test-lab

I'm recording a robo test in android studio emulator device, and I noticed that swipes are never detected by the recorder. Only Buttons clicks / inputs were recorded.
What is the proper way to detect swipes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roboscript Recorder in Android Studio does not capture swipes, because the subsequent actions (e.g., clicks) on the children of swipe-able UI widgets like RecyclerView and AdapterView will produce the necessary swipes, if any, when Robo replays them.

If for some reason, you need to have explicit swipes in your Roboscript, they are pretty straightforward to add manually - https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/android/robo-scripts-reference#swipe